# Setting JFrame icon outside of resoruce

Tags: java, jframe, icons

I'm trying to set custom icon for my app that is placed insde startup folder but icon doesn't showing.

Here are ways what I've tried so far:

1:

```
myApp = new JFrame();
ImageIcon ImageIcon = new ImageIcon(objTools.getApplicationStartUpPath() + "/appicon.ico");
Image Image = ImageIcon.getImage();
myApp.setIconImage(Image);
```

2:

```
myApp.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(objTools.getApplicationStartUpPath() + "/appicon.ico"));
```

And 3rd way that works:

```
myApp.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(APP.class.getResource("/img/appicon.ico")));
```

The last one loads from resources but it's not what I want.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File(PATH)));
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

where `PATH` is a `String` which represent the location of your logo.

Comment: Now, the problem is the `PATH`. Which one did you use?

Comment: frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\appicon.ico")));

Comment: if you execute this code: `for (File f : new File("C://").listFiles()) System.out.println(f.getName());` can you see the line `appicon.ico`?

Comment: Yes, file is present in C root.

Comment: That's very strange. Have you tried to replace your `appicon.ico` with another image? For example a `.jpg` image downloaded from the web? It works?

Comment: It seems that icon file sholud not have extension .ico yet .png. I've tired with the same file but different format (i have both ico and png) and with png works well. Thanks on your patience and help.

Comment: Then, if this is the answer you were looking for, accept it, in order to close it. Thanks to you.